# How do you keep my app in foreground even if chrome is open in OSX using swift?

Tags: swift, macos

I am sharing a picture, for reference  https://i.stack.imgur.com/Puhgr.png.
How do I keep the app window in the foreground even while I am browsing safari/chrome in OSX? In this screenshot case, the play button interface stays over the top of chrome browser. This way I can interact with my app while doing browsing without the need of clicking app and bringing it to foreground.

Comment: An option is to use a floating `NSPanel`

Comment: ok thanks                                                                                      
        window.level = Int(CGWindowLevelForKey(.mainMenuWindow))
                                                                               
        window.collectionBehavior = [.canJoinAllSpaces, .fullScreenAuxiliary] this worked for me